# Insertion in Singly linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

Arrccoding to  algorithm of insertion at the beginning of linked list.
I try to implement this by C as below:

```
void insert(node *head, int value)
{
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        //Create a temp allocation n
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        // Set address of current head (first node) to n
        n->number = value;
        n->next = head;
        //Set head
        head = n;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("List is not exist\n");
    }
}
```

Output of linked list before insert:
1, 2, 3

Output of linked list expect after inset with value = 4:
4, 1, 2, 3

I called the function

```
insert(head, 4)
```

but it seems like nothing happen.

I did debug into the function and everything worked well.
n-> name was updated with argument value and n-> next was updated with current head's pointer.
Then, head was updated by new pointer n in this function.
But when i print the output, it was still 1, 2, 3.

I thought that it could be a local variable problem so i tried to fix by add * to head:

```
n->next = *head;
//Set head
*head = n;
```

But the compiler said that

> assigning to 'struct node *' from incompatible type 'node' (aka
> 'struct node'); remove *

Can someone help me to explain what happened here ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: You should make the argument a pointer to what to modify `node **head`.

Comment: The `head` is a copy which is forgotten on function exit. Another solution is to `return head` and assign by caller.

Comment: If argument for `head` were an `int` that you wanted the function to change, how would you accomplish that?

Comment: Easiest to implement is to return the new head, call it using `head = insert(head, 4);`. no double-pointer shenanigans